# How to use a windows .lib on linux using WINE

Tags: c++, linux, qt, wine, .lib

I have been using Qt (uses c++ code + Qt libraries) on the windows platform and am in the process of porting my project onto the Linux platform.

Using Qt this has been a very simple process and my project works on the Linux platform with barely any changes required.

However, we need to use a 3rd party windows compiled `.lib` with an associated header file. Clearly this file cannot work under Linux, but I have been reading posts that suggest I could use Wine to do this.

So in general my project will work as a normal Linux (Ubuntu) project, but I would like to include this `.lib` file using `Wine`. I have not been able to find a definitive answer "how to do this". I am not sure if you use `Wine` to translate the `.lib` into a `.so` file or if you have to statically link it in with some "Wine-like" convention...

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried compiling under Windows and running the entire program under Wine?

I'm not sure you can splice Wine and Linux programs.

Comment: Hi RobbieE. I have not tried this, this is (in my mind) a last resort! I would really prefer to develop it in linux if possible. However your point is very valid about if you can "splice wine and linux programs"... I have no idea about that either!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want your main program to be native linux and not windows on wine?

Comment: Well, the target for my project is a linux (ubuntu) box. Ideally everything would be linux based just so that we don't need a Windows PC. But other then that.. no there is not :) I mentioned in my comment to Matthieu that I am starting to think this is the way forward. Are there any dis-advantages to running via wine? (same question in my other comment)

Comment: We ended up using wine to get going... so selected this as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can't make hybrid applications with Wine (i.e. link C++ Linux executable with some Linux static libraries and Windows static libraries).

One of the solution I suggest is to encapsulate you Windows library in a Windows program that act as some network service, then you make your Linux application talk to your Windows library through the network.

However, it adds complexity to your software, requires you know how to do some network programing (however, these days it is quite easy to do) and is not suitable to every kind of library, especially if your library has some kind of GUI.

Comment: Hmm... I like your thinking on the "stand-alone" app, it does add complexity but is a potential solution. Though I am starting to come to terms with the prospect of just making the solution in Windows and running it in this Wine environment. I guess a general question is "is there any disadvantages to using wine"... like time costs, reliability, etc? My program only requires very basic things (threads, IP sockets, timers, file IO, and that's about it!).

Comment: I you think about performance penalty, I cannot say... I does not know sufficiently about Wine for that.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine that a hybrid approach would work. In any case, running part of your program as a native application and the other part inside WINE will not give you much advantage over the complete program running in WINE. In either case, WINE is needed.

The main disadvantage of running the complete program in WINE is the look and feel of the GUI which might look a little alien to the system. However, using a proper setup for WINE will minimize the problem. And as a side note, most Linux users are used to different GUI concepts due to the different desktop environments available. Personally I have a lot of GNOME applications running in my KDE desktop.

I would personally try running your program in WINE. It makes development much easier. A circuit simulation tool that is quite famous with electrical engineers uses this approach. It is called LTSpice. While only Windows binaries are available, the developers test it with WINE to ensure that it runs on Linux. Admitted, it is a tool offered for free but the community accepts this approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback, I am starting to get a more confident feeling about the wine approach :) I best go lookup how to deploy my windows app into wine...